# How to remove "on the desktop" suffix from desktop icons - Gnome - Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, icons, shortcuts, gnome-shell

I'd like to remove the *"on the desktop"* text appended to desktop icon names in Ubuntu 17.10.

I've looked into various tools for tweaking Ubuntu, such as `gconf-editor` and `gnome-tweak-tool` but haven't found anything to help me prevent this behavior.

I assume there must be a terminal command to set that string to `""`.
I promise I won't forget they're *on the desktop* anytime soon.

[image]